# Python exception: execute code if a specific exception is raised or else

Tags: python, exception

Let's say I have the following code, that assign `1` and print it in case the value is `None` or not negative.

```
value = None

class NegativeNumber(Exception):
    pass
class NotFound(Exception):
    pass

try:
    if value is None:
        raise NotFound
    elif value < 0:
        raise NegativeNumber
except NegativeNumber:
    print("Error: negative number")
except NotFound:
    value = 1
    print(value)
else:
    value = 1
    print(value)
```

Is there a way to avoid repeat twice to assign `value=1` and print it?

It would be ideal something like `except NotFound or else`, but I have not found anything similar in python.

Comment: I don't see the point of raising ``NotFound`` here. Just don't raise it and things work as desired.

Comment: it's just an example to illustrate my point. The real scenario is the case in which an external function/class raises an error (so no control about it), but one wants to ignore one specific exception but not all the others

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no `except ... or else:` construct. Suppress the exception inside the `try` block to trigger the `else` block for the exception as well:

```py
try:
    try:
        if value is None:
            raise NotFound
        elif value < 0:
            raise NegativeNumber
    except NotFound:
        pass  # suppress exception
except NegativeNumber:
    print("Error: negative number")
else:
    value = 1
    print(value)
```

Instead of using `try`/`except` to suppress the exception, [`contextlib.suppress`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/contextlib.html#contextlib.suppress) can be used instead. This can make the intention clearer, as it explicitly names how the exception is handled.

```py
try:
    with suppress(NotFound):
        if value is None:
            raise NotFound
        elif value < 0:
            raise NegativeNumber
except NegativeNumber:
    print("Error: negative number")
else:
    value = 1
    print(value)
```

Comment: thanks a lot, the solution with `suppress` is awesome